# PHP SQLite3 class 'exec' function not returning false on fail

Tags: php, if-statement, sqlite

I'm using SQLite3, and the SQLite3 class that's built into PHP. The following code does not work in the way I would expect based on other mysql classes that I'm familiar with. The [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.exec.php) says that the `exec` method should return true if the query succeeded, false on failure. However, from what I can see, that doesn't seem to be the case with this.

```
$udb = new SQLite3('app.sqlite');

if($udb->exec("DELETE FROM users WHERE id = $del") != FALSE)
    $message = 'Deleted User';
 else
    $message = 'Could not delete the user.';
```

I would expect that if the row with that ID did not exist, the query would return false or 0 or '0'.  None of these are accurate. In fact, I can't figure out what the function is returning at all.

**Could someone help out with what this error checking `if` block should look like?**

Comment: Have you tried a `var_dump($udb->exec("DELETE FROM users WHERE id = $del"))` to see exactly what it's returning? As far as it not returning `false`, it is executing the query fine -- it just happens that there were no affected rows.

Comment: Right, @jprof, I thought of that. But then the result should be 0 or '0'.  Which then should still be caught with the `!=`, since it doesn't check the type.  So `!= FALSE` should return the same as `!= 0`. But I'll check out `var_dump` for the result.

Comment: `exec()` returns whether or not it successfully executed, not how many rows were affected. If it deleted 5 rows it wouldn't return 5, it would return `true`. With that, if it deleted 0 rows, it would still return `true` because it did successfully execute the query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$udb->changes() > 0` is what you are looking for

http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.changes.php

Answer (score 0):

Successfully executing the query is not the same as a returning **FALSE on failure**.

If you have invalid SQL then it will fail (the query) and it will return false.

Comment: ok, true enough, but not really a solution. How, then would you check if the row was actually deleted?

Comment: Maybe `$udb->changes() > 0` is what you are looking for?

http://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.changes.php

Comment: @sepp: That's perfect. Put it in an answer and I'll give you the rep. :)